# SSRS System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Getting below error for SSRS reports.

Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1.

Comment: To answer your question we need more information. Like a minimal example what you did and what should happen and the code of your expression where the mistakes happens etc...

Comment: I migrated report server to the new server, everything seems ok, but when I am trying to load reports from UI then getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1.

Comment: Looks like you have such a big number which exceeds the limits of Int32 format. Try changing to another bigger format (double, decimal, long Int, etc...)